# EFCodeFirst mapping

Tags: entity-framework

Здравствуйте, с этой технологией недавно ознакомился, и ,наверное, в силу того,что я мало что о ней знаю, есть 1 немного странный вопрос.
        Мне понятно, что CodeFirst классное решение, которое дает самому полностью разработать объектную модель, которая затем будет отображена в таблицы физической БД. Но вот вопрос, а что если та объектная модель, которая я хочу использовать в своем коде, не является прямым отображением таблиц БД? Что я имею в виду ? Например, БД у меня разбита на одни сущности, а объектная модель у меня составная из таблиц, да не все поля этих таблиц еще содержит. Получается, что мне придется сначала создавать объекты, которые являются прямым отображением БД,а потом еще создавать новый объект,который будет частично повторять код тех объектов.Просто сама концепция CodeFirst-a насколько я понял предполагает, чтобы объекты являлись прямым отображением БД и дальнейшая работа производилась с этими объектами,но ведь так не всегда получается.Возможно я тут написал бред.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не бред, почему же? Хороший вопрос.

CodeFirst можно настраивать, указывая [аннотациями](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583) и в коде ([[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2), [[2]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620)) какие именно таблицы будут созданы, и как они будут отображаться на ваши данные. (Для справки, [вот так](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962) будет сделано по умолчанию.)

Надеюсь, это поможет.

Comment: Ага,спасибо,помогло.

Comment: @nvse: пожалуйста!